# Can't break for loop because of if?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a piece of code and I am trying to `break` for loop, but I can't. Is the reason it's inside the `if` and if that then what is the other way?

```
    var myMessages = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < bots.length; i++){
        if ( bots[i].getInventory().getItems().length < capacity ){  
            var executed = false;
            bots[i].createDeposit({
                steamid: req.query.steamid,
                token: req.query.token,
                itemsFromThem: uniqueItems,
                message: req.query.message,
                callback: function( err, dbTradeId ){
                    if ( !executed ){
                        executed = true;
                        if ( !err && dbTradeId ){
                            res.json({ result: 1, dbTradeId: dbTradeId });
                            break; //Break Is Here
                        } else {
                            console.log('» Tried to create deposit, but',err);
                            myMessages.push("Problem");
                            res.json({ error: err });                   
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('» Tried to create deposit, but no bot found(2)');
            myMessages.push("Available bot not found(2)");
        }
    }
    } else {
        console.log('» Tried to create deposit, but no bot found');
        myMessages.push("Available bot not found"); 
    }
} catch(e){
    return res.json({ error: e.message, stack: e.stack });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify( myMessages));
```

Comment: It's a callback function.

Comment: Oh I am sorry for not knowing how to google.

Comment: @PraveenKumar returning true doesn't work for me. It just continues to do the thing.

Comment: Yeah, you need to take a different approach in this case. You cannot determine to break the loop from the callback.

Comment: Hmm, but how is it possible then to stop it going if one was successful? I have to have that loop there, to test each bot. I would love to do if it finds one, then it won't continue the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your break is inside a closure callback, what you are trying there is impossible. The callback is not invoked at the time of your loop. Even if it is, it's a different lexical scope, which loses access to break the loop.